# Connect to Amazon (AWS) EC2 instance via browser

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am having trouble connecting to an Amazon Elastic Cloud Computer Instance via a browser.
I attempted going to ****************.compute-1.amazonaws.com , but the browser returns that the connection has timed out.

I can connect via ssh and winscp. That is how I uploaded a web app I developer. I have also created a security group and added rules to open ports 22 and 80.

Do I have to assign the security group to the instance somehow?

The security group's rules also do not have a source IP, well they do its 0.0.0.0/0

I would really appreciate any and all help in getting this site ' viewable ' via a browser.

Comment: Did you finally succeed in finding a solution?

Answer (score 23):

By default, your instances will only be in the `default` security group. If it's an EC2 instance you cannot change security groups while the instance is running, you'll have to specify them in advance. If it's a VPC instance you can change security groups at runtime.

## Add the rule to the `default` group

You can however add the rule to allow port 80 to that `default` security group; just don't create a new security group as it can not be associated with the running instance.

## Is the web server up?

Also, make sure that your web server is up and running. From your instance (using SSH shell access), check if the right process is listening on port 80, using the command `netstat -lnp`. You should then see a row with `proto` `tcp` and a `Local Address` ending in :80. The IP Address listed should be either 0.0.0.0 (meaning 'any IP') or a specific IP of a listening network interface.

## Web server not up

If you are in need of a web server, take a look at Apache or Nginx. They both support PHP.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added the rules to the default security group that the instance is using, that didn't help.

Then I tried to run the command to see if the right processes are listening ( netstat -lnp ) and this is what the terminal returned: http://www.anonmgur.com/up/0e479fde3637cf97ec6fe3eeb47d3a50.png

Also once I get PHP installed, how do I get it up and running?

Comment: I tried sudo service httpd start and that starts the php / Apache server, right?

Comment: @IrfanM: Follow-up advice on how to get a web server up and running on your instance is beyond the scope of this question; try opening a new, more specific question or searching for tutorials.

Comment: I also had to modify my iptables but the important part is to check which security group is actually linked to the instance. (its written on the instance summary page)...

Answer (score 3):

I had also faced similar issue with ec2 micro instance. I was using Red-Hat AMI. Despite of opening ports 8081 in security group, I was not able to a telnet to the host port. Disabling the iptable did the trick for me:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to disable firewall if you use windows for your server.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while setting up redash AMI image on AWS. Inbound security rules should be changed when instance is not running. Let's say if the instance is running (meaning it's active and started); If you change the inbound rules of that machine you'll still face firewall issue. So Stop the machine on which you want to change the inbound rules on. Change the inbound rules. Start the machine now. Now you can hit the machine url from the ip you just opened the access to the machine to.

Comment: Can you expand on this? This feels like the start of a decent answer, but it's a bit thin.

Answer (score 0):

The EC2 instance firewall is maybe enabled.
Check it with this command:

```
sudo systemctl status firewalld
```

if enabled you can disable it with :

```
sudo systemctl disable firewalld
```

or setup rules to allow port 80 trafic